# Production build ignores a style file?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, vite

I have a new Laravel app built with Jetstream and Livewire with Blade. In order to make one small piece of the UI change color, I had to add a custom CSS file:

```css
/* resources/css/nouislider.css */

.noUi-connect {
    background-color: #a17656;
}
```

And I call this file in my main JavaScript file since I read somewhere recently (maybe the Vite docs?) that this is preferred way to make it available in the project:

```js
/* resources/js/app.js */

import './bootstrap';
import '../css/nouislider.css';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

This works fine when I check out the results locally with `npm run dev`, but if I instead run `npm run build`, the brown color I specified in `nouislider.css` does not take effect and it shows the default turquoise color.

`npm run dev`:
[image: with npm run dev]

`npm run build`:
[image: with npm run build]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you paste error message? what does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @Jack I apologize for not being as clear as I could. I have edited the question to better illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Vue will place the vendor CSS files *after* my custom ones when running `npm run build`, for some reason. And, of course, thanks to the cascading nature of CSS, it overrides my custom color.

So, I just had to force it to take precedence:

```css
/* resources/css/nouislider.css */

.noUi-connect {
    background-color: #a17656 !important;
}
```

Which appears to have solved the problem, if inelegantly.